# Android requesting location instead of bluetooth permissions; depending on android version

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, bluetooth

I am debugging a react native app that absolutely needs bluetooth permissions, however at the moment in android the bluetooth permissions are returning `unavailable`. 
I am requesting permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

And I am checking the status of bluetooth permissions like this:

```
const checkBluetoothPermissions = () => {
    requestMultiple(
      Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? [
            PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          ]
        : [PERMISSIONS.IOS.BLUETOOTH_PERIPHERAL],
    ).then(_ => {
      console.log('permission results', _);
    });
  };
```

What is being logged from this function is
`permission results {"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION": "granted", "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT": "unavailable", "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN": "unavailable"}`
And when installing the app the only permission that is asked is `location` and I do not know why.
I followed the instructions here: [react-native-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions).

There is no issue on IOS from the same codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

and call this function

```
import {
  requestMultiple,
  PERMISSIONS,
  RESULTS,
} from "react-native-permissions";

const getStatusPermissions = async () => {
  const androidOsVer =
    Platform.os === "android" && Platform.constants["Release"];
  let androidPermissions = [PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH_SCAN];

  if (androidOsVer > 11) {
    androidPermissions.push(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
  }

  const statusesList = await requestMultiple(androidPermissions);

  return Object.values(statusesList).some((el) => el === RESULTS.GRANTED);
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you, this is working. So what is the difference? Is there something wrong with `requestMultiple`?

Comment: no thats fine, its related to platform version, see I have added one check on above 11 we need that

Answer (score 0):

It should implicitly include BLUETOOTH_SCAN and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT by requesting the BLUETOOTH permission. Because location permission is frequently needed for Bluetooth functionality, make sure it's also being requested.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 const checkBluetoothPermissions = () => {
    requestMultiple(
      Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? [
            PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH,
            PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          ]
        : [PERMISSIONS.IOS.BLUETOOTH_PERIPHERAL],
    ).then((results) => {
      console.log('permission results', results);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or lower, declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file
here **location must be turned ON for scanning**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

- BLUETOOTH permission to make connection to Bluetooth device.
- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to scan for Bluetooth devices.

If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

- BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission to make connection to Bluetooth device.
- BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission to scan for Bluetooth devices.

neverForLocation flag is necessary or else scan will not work properly.

**NB:** If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher and you are scanning for a **BLE beacon device**,
**don't** add flag neverForLocation and **location must be turned ON for scanning**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

You might be using a device with Android 11 (API level 30) or below, BLUETOOTH_SCAN and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT are not defined for those devices (Bluetooth permissions are included in the Location permission, you should just request for Location permission)